# Is it possible to embed a TTF or OTF font file in a C++ application?

Tags: windows, cocoa, fonts, macos

Is it possible to embed a TTF or OTF font file in a C++ application so that application can use it without installing it on target machine? Any thoughts are welcome. (target platforms are going to be Windows and Macintosh). Purpose: Font is a private one and should not be available to the users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OS X](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/GeneralPurposeKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009253-SW8): Include the font in the app’s `Resources` directory, then add the value `ATSApplicationFontsPath` to the app’s `Info.plist` containing the path relative to the Resources directory.

Windows: MSDN has an article [for Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y505zzfw.aspx) using the `System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection` class and one [for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303.aspx) using the `System.Windows.Media.FontFamily` class. This is assuming you’re using C++/CLI and the .NET GUI frameworks; it probably won’t apply for MFC.

Comment: Thanks! I think I can use PrivateFontCollection. Working on a Win32 application.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, got to know that a TTF font is simply a byte array. Just take a hexdump and prepare the byte array (taking care of the endianness, most modern architectures are little endian).

Following thread has details:

https://twitter.com/awmanoj/status/1071718063647580161

In golang, there is also a generator of the byte array. Quite trivial to implement the same in another language like Java/C++ per the need.